# Why would you write your own Random Number Generator?

Tags: java, c#, c++, random, numbers

I've read a lot of guides on how to write your own random number generator, so I'm interested in the reasons why you would write your own since most languages already provide functions for generating random numbers:

Like C++

```
    srand(time(NULL));
    rand();
```

C#

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    rand.Next(100);
```

and Java

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    rand.nextInt(0, 100);
```

I'm mainly looking for advantages to using your own.

Comment: Your question sound opinion-based instead of technical facts.

Comment: Interesting question but not suited for SO. You will mostly get opinion.

Comment: There is the possibility that the .NET Random is bugged... https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/634761/system-random-serious-bug This could be a reason :)

Comment: There are no truly random number generators: http://engineering.mit.edu/ask/can-computer-generate-truly-random-number

Comment: @TimStoddard I guess this question will get you quite some downvotes; as the answers would be pretty broad/opinion based. Nonetheless: the only reason to write your own customer PRNG can be: you are not happy with the properties of the existing ones. Meaning: you have a very deep mathematical understanding of the whole subject; and you come to the point that you think that for a very special use case; you will need a very special solution. The only other reason to create PRNG would be to learn how to do it; and to encounter the many many potential mistakes on that route.

Comment: I can think of technical, non-opinion based answers to this question.  In particular, I `rand` in C++ is on the verge of being deprecated, and the reasons behind it should be documented in various standards documents.  The reasons behind the C++11 random number generator features can be explained, and an example given of what kind of random number generator that isn't provided in C++11 might be written.  A discussion of distributions in C++11, and why you might want to write your own, can be added.  Nothing strongly opinion based. You can also answer this question with opinions, but who cares?

Comment: @Yakk But still the question would be still very broad. It is one thing to ask about technical subtleties of existing PNRG implementations; it is a completely different thing to talk about "all of them" in general.

Comment: Anyhow, voting to reopen.  There are hard technical reasons describing why you'd write your own random number generator that are not a matter of opinion.  What features you'd want is a matter of opinion, but that isn't what this question asks.  @EddyG no, it does not requires *every* reason to write your own RNG, it asks for why you'd write your own.  And a brief sketch of RNG properties and tradeoffs, and the fact that the language built-ins RNGs *make a choice*, and you might want any other choice, is enough to answer the question.

Comment: A good reason to write your own, or at least (better) to use a library instead of just rand() is the statistical distribution of numbers it provides.  Not all rand() functions are equal.  For example: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Distributions.html

Comment: In some languages, the provided functionality is awful. C's `rand` has global state and most implementations are quite bad (short period, fails simple statistical tests). Java's is pretty bad too, it's specified to be a LCG (again, short period and not very random). Now that doesn't mean everyone should write their *own*, but they should look beyond the standard capabilities.

Comment: @ControlAltDel In programming contexts, unless context indicates otherwise or the distinction is important for what one is trying to do, it is understood that "random" means "pseudorandom".

Comment: I rolled my own because I relied on providing a seed and getting the same sequence of randoms (generating a complex system of objects the same way several times using only a single seed - think "No Mans Sky"). However, it turned out that somewhere along the line Java's implementation of random changed and suddenly nothing was the same anymore... I don't use it for cryptography but the complexity of the system overall seems to make things random enough... (See RANF here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator)

Answer (score 2):

If you've done your research and found out that the default generator is horrible (as is the case in C or Excel, or with IBM's infamous `randu`), you might be motivated to download or implement a better generator.  However, unless you have a very deep understanding of probability, statistics, and numerical methods, you should under no circumstances try to create your own. Even such luminaries as John von Neumann have screwed up royally on this.

Another reason might be to get cross-platform reproducibility of results.

Answer (score 2):

Never, ever, roll-your-own cryptography or random number generation unless you are *very* comfortable with the higher math involved. Here's a short test: if you understand probability distributions, linear feedback shift registers, the incomplete gamma function, and the Chinese remainder theorem, you *might* be qualified to roll your own.

Otherwise, use a generator provided by someone who does understand these things. The one built into your language might not be. So look for add-on libraries with good reputations.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reasons is right in your question..:

> most languages already provide functions

They do but they are more often than not incompatible.

I had to write one once because the (lightweight) encryption I wrote was using a different language (Powerscript) than the decryption (VB) and their Random generators were not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, even though you want a sequence of random numbers, you might want the same exact sequence of random numbers (for debugging or other purposes).

In a portable program, designed to be run on different systems with different libraries, and possibly different random number generators, accomplishing the goal stated above might not be possible.

If you instead implement your own, you would have control over this, and could make it behave the same on a multitude of systems, rather than relying on the provided implementation.

Also, as mentioned in a comment, a provided implementation may be bugged somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Stock random number generators are usually pseudo-random number generators in most languages.

A pseudo-random number generator starts with some state, and uses it to produce an unpredictable sequence of seemingly uniform numbers.

There are many different pseudo-random number generators that have been researched.  They have different advantages and disadvantages -- some are more random, some have longer periods, some are cryptographically strong and difficult to work out the seed from previous samples, some are fast, etc.

The one picked for a given language is going to be some compromise of the above features.  In some cases, the one picked will be known to be a poor one, but for legacy reasons is left alone as the "stock" random number generator (`rand()` is an example of a poor random number generator).  If you need different features than your given language random number generator picked as important, writing your own (or finding one) is about the only way to get it.

In some languages, the random number generator (or the distribution generator) is under specified, or subject to change between revisions of the language.  If you need stability of your random number generator (say, you are using it to procedurally generate a game universe from a small seed -- see the classic game star control 2), writing it yourself may be required, even if it is a clone of the standard one on your system.

If you need your random number generator to be stable from one language to another, each language is going to have made different choices.

In C++11, the old `rand()` was mostly deprecated, and a new library with 3 engines, 10 predefined generators, 3 engine adapters, 21 distributions, and 1 non-pseudo random number generator (`random_device`) was added.  The distributions are under-specified, while the generators are not: if you need cross-compiler compatibility of results from a given seed state, you would need to write your own distributions.

Even in C++11 with that embarrassment of riches, the exact trade offs you want might not be available.  So you'd have to write your own.

Note that C++11's set of generators was mostly written prior to C++11 being in existence.  It was written because `rand()` was considered useless, and people wrote libraries with their own random number generators.  Best practices where gathered, and formalized in that version of C++.  So another reason to learn how to write them is that your language of choice will need to be improved, and programmers are the ones who need to do it.

For an in-depth discussion of pseudo-random number generator properties, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) has an acceptable place to start.  Here it mentions that Java's JCG is a low quality one.

Answer (score -1):

The generators you list are all PRNGs. These particular PRNGs are not suitable for gaming, scientific, or cryptographic applications.

Comment: Nonsense. A good PRNG is more than suitable for gaming, simulation, Monte Carlo integration, and other uses. Many good cryptographically secure ones exist as well. They are difficult to make, but far from impossible.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I never said a *good* PRNG wasn't suitable for these applications, just that the ones he listed weren't. I suspect the other downvoters are downvoting me because of what they imagine I'm saying rather than what I actually said.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Hopefully the rephrasing will improve this a bit.